# Вызвать функцию в iframe при наступлении unload у родительской страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, как можно вызвать js-функцию в документе, находящемся в iframe при закрытии родительского окна?
`$(window)on('unload', function(){})`
не реагирует. Реагирует только, к примеру, при перезагрузке фрейма (по нажатию соотв. пунка в контекстном меню iframe)

Суть в том, что в iframe находится приложение и по закрытию странички хотелось бы делать disconnect();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main.html:

```
<html>
<body id="B1">
<iframe src="/f1.html"></iframe>
<a href="/">go</a>
</body>
```

f1.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is frame</h1>
<script>
$( window.parent ).unload(function() {
    alert("parent window unloading");
});
</script>
</body>
```

Работает в FF. 
Для Chrome(и для FF) корректный вариант скрпта из f1.html:

```
<script>
$(window.parent).on('beforeunload', function(){
    alert("parent window unloading");
});
</script>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не срабатывает.
Пробовал в chrome 60.0.3112.113

Использую jquery-3.2.1

Comment: У меня под рукой был 2.х. И это работает при рефреше и уходе со страницы по ссылке. Если вы просто закрываете окно браузера, то да - не срабатывает

Comment: В общем, у меня вместо alert было задан вызов функции diconnect();. И это не срабатывало, но если поместить не вызов функции, а код функции, то все сработало.
Ваш ответ был наиболее правильным, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('iframe').ready(function(){
    alert('Работает?');
})
```

можно попробовать

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
        alert('2');

    });
```

Comment: Какое отличие этих фрагментов?

Answer (score 0):

**Никак**. Нельзя обращаться к содержимому дочернего фрейма.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame